# Python: Non-blocking read from file/stream in Cygwin

Tags: python, terminal, cygwin

If I was on a Unix system, then I could do something like this in Python to open a file in non-blocking mode:

`fd = os.open(filepath, os.O_NONBLOCK)`

However, in Windows, `os.O_NONBLOCK` does not exist, and one would get an `os` module error `'module' object has no attribute O_NONBLOCK`, if we tried to use it. We would have to do something like this for non-blocking input: https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/prompt_toolkit/terminal/win32_input.py#L99

How does non-blocking input work in Cygwin though? Does Cygwin emulate something similar to the `O_NONBLOCK` option?

Answer (score 1):

O_NONBLOCK can be used in C programming. You can see the definitions in the header file /usr/include/sys/_default_fcntl.h

```
#define _FNONBLOCK  0x4000  /* non blocking I/O (POSIX style) */
#define O_NONBLOCK  _FNONBLOCK
```

You could try the magic number 0x4000 directly.