# How to use the new support for ANSI escape sequences in the Windows 10 console?

Tags: python, cmd, windows-10, windows-console

The latest Windows 10 updates include [support for ANSI escape sequences](http://www.nivot.org/blog/post/2016/02/04/Windows-10-TH2-%28v1511%29-Console-Host-Enhancements) in conhost.exe.

[image]

I have been able to confirm that the escape sequences are properly picked up in cmd.exe, so I have the necessary updates. In particular, I tried typing in `prompt $e[?25l`, which hides the cursor, and then `prompt $e[?25h`, which again shows the cursor.

However, if I start a Python interpreter, and then do the following:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.write("\033[?25l")
```

Well, the cursor isn't hidden. How can I set things up the right way so that the console is able to get escape sequences from Python?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem is that the Python interpreter doesn't enable the processing of ANSI escape sequences.  The ANSI sequences work from the Windows command prompt because `cmd` does enable them. If you start Python from the command prompt you'll find the ANSI sequences do work, including the ones for enabling and disabling the cursor.  That's because `cmd` has already enabled them for that console window.

If you want have something you can click on to start the Python interpreter with ANSI escapes enabled you can create a shortcut that runs a command something like `cmd /c C:\PythonXY\python`.

Another, harder, solution would be to use ctypes to enable ANSI escape sequence processing for the console window by calling the `SetConsoleMode` Windows API with the [`ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033(v=vs.85).aspx#ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING) flag set. For example:

```
import ctypes

kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
kernel32.SetConsoleMode(kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11), 7)
```

Comment: Hi Ross -- thanks for this really nice answer :) It seems you do a lot of console related stuff, and I am wondering -- do you also know how to achieve non-blocking input in a Windows console, similar to how one might do it in Linux, by using the O_NONBLOCK flag? Python Prompt Toolkit achieves non-blocking input by using a special read function exposed by the Windows API: https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/prompt_toolkit/terminal/win32_input.py#L99 -- there doesn't seem to be a flag I can set, which would then allow `sys.stdin.read()` to not block?

Comment: @user89 No, unfortunately there's no equivalent to the O_NONBLOCK flag. Windows uses a different model involving waiting on events on handles and overlapped I/O (the later isn't supported for console handles). You'll either need to delve into the Windows API through ctypes or let something like curses handle it for you. Curses support isn't shipped with Python for Windows, but you can download a port separately, see: https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/curses.html

Comment: Makes sense -- I guess I'll just wait to see how the Windows console improves (especially with the upcoming release of bash on Windows), and for now stick to using VMs with Linux in order to run+develop console apps.

Comment: @user89 Bash for Windows is part of their new Linux subsystem for Windows. Unfortunately, it's little better integrated than using VMs with Linux, the file system is shared but that's it. You might look at Cygwin instead, which in addition to letting you run Windows programs from bash and "Linux" programs from the Windows command line, it works on current version of Windows 10, along with older versions of Windows.

Comment: Cygwin doesn't have support for flags like O_NONBLOCK either though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696267/python-non-blocking-read-from-file-stream-in-cygwin -- but maybe I am not understanding something right?

Comment: @user89 I'm guessing that person was trying to use the native Windows port of Python under Cygwin rather than Cygwin port. The O_NONBLOCK flag exists in the Cygwin port. For example this works: `print os.open("/dev/tty", os.O_NONBLOCK | os.O_RDWR, 0)`.

Comment: (that person was me :p) Wow, that's absolutely awesome! I did not know this about Cygwin! Thank you so much!

Comment: @RossRidge Sorry for my ignorance, why the number "7"?

Comment: @HenriqueDias It's the equivalent of `ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT|ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT|ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` which is the equivalent of `0x0001|0x0002|0x0004` which equals 7.  Python can't include the C header file that defines these flags, so I've just substituted the number 7 that they end up evaluating to. The first two flags are on by default and enable the normal console output processing that you would expect, and the third is the flag that enables processing of ANSI escape sequences and isn't enabled by default.

Comment: @RossRidge thanks a lot! I was trying to do the same as you did but in Go and I found this post and your answer. Then I tried with 7 and it worked (I've been trying with 0x0004 before). I just didn't know why 7. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

This adaptation of some code I proposed [here](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/15758#issuecomment-370630896) should help get you started. Enables **ANSI VT** mode (virtual terminal processing) on **Windows 10**. Pass in argument value `1` for *stdout* or `2` *stderr*.

```
def _windows_enable_ANSI(std_id):
    """Enable Windows 10 cmd.exe ANSI VT Virtual Terminal Processing."""
    from ctypes import byref, POINTER, windll, WINFUNCTYPE
    from ctypes.wintypes import BOOL, DWORD, HANDLE

    GetStdHandle = WINFUNCTYPE(
        HANDLE,
        DWORD)(('GetStdHandle', windll.kernel32))

    GetFileType = WINFUNCTYPE(
        DWORD,
        HANDLE)(('GetFileType', windll.kernel32))

    GetConsoleMode = WINFUNCTYPE(
        BOOL,
        HANDLE,
        POINTER(DWORD))(('GetConsoleMode', windll.kernel32))

    SetConsoleMode = WINFUNCTYPE(
        BOOL,
        HANDLE,
        DWORD)(('SetConsoleMode', windll.kernel32))

    if std_id == 1:       # stdout
        h = GetStdHandle(-11)
    elif std_id == 2:     # stderr
        h = GetStdHandle(-12)
    else:
        return False

    if h is None or h == HANDLE(-1):
        return False

    FILE_TYPE_CHAR = 0x0002
    if (GetFileType(h) & 3) != FILE_TYPE_CHAR:
        return False

    mode = DWORD()
    if not GetConsoleMode(h, byref(mode)):
        return False

    ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING = 0x0004
    if (mode.value & ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING) == 0:
        SetConsoleMode(h, mode.value | ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING)
    return True
```

Comment: It doesn't work, gives "NameError: name 'compat_ctypes_WINFUNCTYPE' is not defined"

Comment: As the author mentioned, this code came from a GitHub issue comment regarding youtube-dl. The missing function is defined in youtube-dl (you can use the GitHub search functions to find it there). If you are not using PyPy, then `compat_ctypes_WINFUNCTYPE` = `WINFUNCTYPE` so you can replace those calls accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

The [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) package enables ANSI codes in Windows.

Usage:

```py
from colorama import init
init()
```

After that ANSI codes should work.

Comment: great answer! I've used colorama, but did not know that init() would enable support on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Use the solution suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/293633/18487576

Run:

```
os.system('color')
```

to enable color mode on the terminal.

I was using the accepted answer with ctypes until I discovered this. This solution does not require any additional installations or native API chicanery.

This command is not an executable file, but a specific command within the Windows cmd terminal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/color

Its official use is to change foreground/background colors of the shell. The fact that it will activate ANSI/VT100 is apparently undocumented.

Comment: Thank you. This is such a simple solution, works fine for cmd and powershell in Win10 22H2