# Colored text output in PowerShell console using ANSI / VT100 codes

Tags: powershell, windows-console, ansi-escape, vt100

I wrote a program which prints a string, which contains [ANSI escape sequences](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/10/11/whats-new-in-windows-console-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update/) to make the text colored. But it doesn't work as expected in the default Windows 10 console, as you can see in the screenshot.

The program output appears with the escape sequences as printed characters.
If I feed that string to PowerShell via a variable or piping, the output appears as intended (red text).

How can I achieve that the program prints colored text without any workarounds?

[image]

This is my program source (Haskell) - but the language is not relevant, just so you can see how the escape sequences are written.

```
main = do
    let red = "\ESC[31m"
    let reset = "\ESC[39m"
    putStrLn $ red ++ "RED" ++ reset
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Note:

- The following **applies to *regular* console windows** on Windows (provided by `conhost.exe`), which are used *by default*, including when a console application is launched from a GUI application.
- By contrast, the console windows (terminals) provided by **[Windows Terminal](https://aka.ms/windowsterminal)** as well as **Visual Studio Code's *integrated terminal*** provide **support for VT / ANSI escape sequences *by default***, for *all* console applications.

---

While **console windows in Windows 10 do support VT (Virtual Terminal) / ANSI escape sequences** *in principle*, **support is turned *OFF by default***.

You have three options:

- (a) **Activate support *globally by default, persistently***, via the registry, as detailed in [this SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/1300251/139307).

  - In short: In registry key `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]`, create or set the `VirtualTerminalLevel` DWORD value to `1`

    - From PowerShell, you can do this *programmatically* as follows:
      `Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Console VirtualTerminalLevel -Type DWORD 1`
    - From `cmd.exe` (also works from PowerShell):
      `reg add HKCU\Console /v VirtualTerminalLevel /t REG_DWORD /d 1`
  - Open a new console window for changes to take effect.
  - See caveats below.
- (b) **Activate support *from inside your program, for that program (process) only***, with a call to the `SetConsoleMode()` Windows API function.

  - See details below.
- (c) **Ad-hoc workaround, *from PowerShell***:

  - *PowerShell (Core) 7+*: Enclose external-program calls in `(...)` (invariably collects all output first before printing):

    - `(.\test.exe)`
  - Streaming *Windows PowerShell-only* alternative: Pipe output from external programs to `Write-Host`

    - `.\test.exe | Out-Host`
  - See details below.

---

#### Re (a):

The registry-based approach **invariably activates VT support *globally*, i.e., for *all* console windows**, irrespective of what shell / program runs in them:

- Individual executables / shells can still deactivate support for themselves, if desired,  using method (b).
- Conversely, however, this means that the output of any program that doesn't explicitly control VT support will be subject to interpretation of VT sequences; while this is generally desirable, hypothetically this could lead to misinterpretation of output from programs that *accidentally* produce output with VT-like sequences.

Note:

- While there *is* a mechanism that allows console-window settings to be scoped by startup executable / window title, via *subkeys* of `[HKEY_CURRENT_USR\Console]`, the `VirtualTerminalLevel` value seems not to be supported there.
- Even if it were, however, it wouldn't be a *robust* solution, because opening a console window via a *shortcut* file (`*.lnk`) (e.g. from the Start Menu or Task Bar) wouldn't respect these settings, because `*.lnk` files have settings *built into them*; while you can modify these built-in settings via the `Properties` GUI dialog, as of this writing the `VirtualTerminalLevel` setting is not surfaced in that GUI.

---

#### Re (b):

Calling the [`SetConsoleMode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) Windows API function *from inside the program (process)*, as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#example-of-enabling-virtual-terminal-processing), is cumbersome even in C# (due to requiring P/Invoke declarations), and **may not be an option**:

- for programs written in languages from which calling the Windows API is not supported.
- if you have a preexisting executable that you cannot modify.

In that event, option (c) (from PowerShell), discussed next, may work for you.

---

#### Re (c):

**PowerShell automatically activates VT (virtual terminal) support *for itself*** when it starts (in recent releases of Windows 10 this applies to both Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) 7+) - but that **does *not* extend to external programs *called from* PowerShell**, in either edition, as of v7.3.2.

- **Separately**, in v7.2+ there is the **[`$PSStyle.OutputRendering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psstyle) *preference variable***, which **controls whether *PowerShell* commands produce colored output *via the [formatting system](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview)***, such as the colored headers of `Get-ChildItem` output. However, this setting has no effect on (direct) output from *external programs*. `$PSStyle.OutputRendering` defaults to `Host`, meaning that only formatted output that prints to the terminal (console) is colored. `$PSStyle.OutputRendering = 'PlainText'` disables coloring, and `$PSStyle.OutputRendering = 'Ansi'` makes it unconditional; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69065907/45375) for more information.

However, as a **workaround** you can ***relay* an external program's (stdout) output via *PowerShell's* (success) output stream**, in which case **VT sequences *are* recognized**:

- As of PowerShell (Core) 7.3.2, this only works either by **enclosing the call in `(...)`** or by using [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string), but note that *all output is invariably collected first* before it is printed.<sup>[1]</sup>

  ```bash
  (.\test.exe)
  ```
- In *Windows PowerShell*, in addition to the above, *streaming* the relayed output is possible too, by piping to `Write-Host` (`Out-Host`, `Write-Output` or `Out-String -Stream` would work too)

  ```bash
  .\test.exe | Write-Host
  ```
- Note: You need these techniques only if you want to print to the *console*. If, by contrast, you want to *capture* the external program's output (including the escape sequences), use `$capturedOutput = .\test.exe`

**Character-encoding caveat**: Windows PowerShell by default expects output from external programs to use the OEM code page, as defined by the legacy system locale (e.g., `437` on US-English systems) and as reflected in `[console]::OutputEncoding`.
.NET console programs respect that setting automatically, but for non-.NET programs (e.g., Python scripts) that use a different encoding (and produce not just pure ASCII output (in the 7-bit range)), you must (at least temporarily) specify that encoding by assigning to `[console]::OutputEncoding`; e.g., for UTF-8:
`[console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::Utf8`.
Note that this is not only necessary for the VT-sequences workaround, but **generally necessary for PowerShell to interpret non-ASCII characters correctly**.

PowerShell *Core* (v6+), unfortunately, as of v7.3.2, still defaults to the OEM code page too, but that should be considered a *bug* (see [GitHub issue #7233](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7233)), given that it otherwise defaults to *UTF-8 without BOM*.

---

<sup>[1] Using `Out-String -Stream` or its built-in wrapper function, `oss`, is tempting in order to achieve streaming output, but this no longer works as of PowerShell 7.3.2, *possibly* due to the optimization implemented in [GitHub PR #16612](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/16612).</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot.
@Szabolcs pointed out that you can use `os.system('color')`
see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal

Comment: As of v7.3 it defaults now to `ANSI`

Comment: @RobertLove, what defaults to `ANSI`? This answer discusses support for ANSI / VT escape sequences, which are also supported in Windows PowerShell and earlier PowerShell (Core) versions. However, only recent PowerShell (Core) versions extend that support to _external programs_. Note that, in v7.2+, there's `$PSStyle.OutputRendering` for controlling the coloring behavior of PowerShell's own commands; this variable can be set to `Ansi`, but  its default is `Host`. I've updated the answer to clarify how `$PSStyle.OutputRendering` comes into play.

Comment: @mklement0 - With your last comment is now untrue.  From release notes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-73?view=powershell-7.3  the state that they change default for $PSStyle.OutputRendering to `Ansi`

Comment: @RobertLove, yes, that's what they _state_ (as of this writing), but it isn't true: Just run `$PSStyle.OutputRendering` (in a session started with `-NoProfile`, to be safe). I've opened an issue to get this corrected: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/9497

Answer (score 18):

Thanks to user mklement0 for making me aware that VT support is not enabled automatically. This made me look in the right direction and I found [this helpful post](https://superuser.com/a/1300251/776768).

So to answer my question: Add or set the registry key

```
HKCU:\Console  -  [DWORD] VirtualTerminalLevel = 1
```

Restart the console and it works.

Comment: Thanks for digging deeper - it hadn't even occurred to me that there might be global switch, but it makes perfect sense. I took the liberty of incorporating your findings into my updated answer - including programmatic ways to flip the switch and associated caveats - in an effort to provide a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

For Haskell specifically, you need to call the [hSupportsANSIWithoutEmulation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ansi-terminal-0.11/docs/System-Console-ANSI.html#v:hSupportsANSIWithoutEmulation) function to enable ANSI escape sequences  in your program  on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes across this, and isn't getting it to work, hopefully this helps.

I've been doing the basic [`SetConsoleMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) method to change the console mode to `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` (`0x0004`). This didn't work for me.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36760881) related to python and the line

```python
kernel32.SetConsoleMode(kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11), 7)
```

caught my attention. Apparently if you put in `7` instead of `4`(which is, from MSDN, `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING`), you're able to use ANSI sequences.

I'm not sure which terminals this works and doesn't work for. So far Windows PowerShell, Command Prompt, and ConHost all accept it. I have no idea how to color text on Linux, nor do I know if this method works on older versions of Windows.