# Colored text output on PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell

I use the following color class found in this question ["Print in terminal with colors?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors)

```
class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

print(bcolors.FAIL + "some error" + bcolors.ENDC)
```

When I run this in my python script editor I get the output in the correct red error color:

```
some error
[Finished in 18.782s]
```

However when I run from command prompt, or using powershell (my intended console output) I get the this output:

> [91msome error[0m
>
> (there are arrows before each "[" but would not show every time I press save)

**update:**

Here is a capture of the output:

[image]

This seems a very attractive approach because I do not have to download or import any new modules and could just include it in a few lines in my script. This was voted  to be the best answer but I could not get it working because it seems to interpret `\033` as some ASCII for the arrow sign.

Comment: This might be relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680709/colored-text-output-in-powershell-console-using-ansi-vt100-codes

Comment: @Aaron this was really helpful thank you. Apparently I didn't get that as a "suggested" or "related" when I wrote my question.

Answer (score 3):

In the linked answer you can also find the following statement:

This will work on unixes including OS X, linux and ***windows (provided you use ANSICON, or in Windows 10 provided you enable VT100 emulation)***.

Since you are asking about powershell which of the two have you tried?

.

Perhaps you might rather want to look into [Colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/)

Comment: It seems I have to because my entire applications runs on one shell and even if I enable Virtual Terminal Sequences. I would need to restart the the shell for the changes to take effect. Thank you for pointing out the issue.