# coloredlogs not displaying "correctly" in windows powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I wrote some simple codes:

```
import coloredlogs

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

coloredlogs.install(logger =  logger)


logger.info('this is some info')
logger.debug('this is some debug')
logger.warning('this is some warning')
logger.error('this is some error')
```

in VSCode, when I run this script in the integrated windows powershell, i see:

[image: the display from VS code power shell (the desired color schemes)]

however when i run the exact same code in the windows powershell i see this; where the color theme is much less desirable from the one rendered from the VS code integrated PS terminal.

[image: the display from standalone power shell]

how can I config my windows powershell so that the color rendering is the same as the one from the VS code powershell terminal?

Comment: It's python code, right? Are you sure you're using PowerShell to run it in VSCode and you're not using a native python thingy by using some VSCode extension? Did you try to run it in a bare cmd or using the apropiate interpreter to see whenever it makes a difference? You could check [Colored text output in PowerShell console using ANSI / VT100 codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680709/colored-text-output-in-powershell-console-using-ansi-vt100-codes) as it might be related.

Comment: Thanks Seth for sharing the link.  Very useful.  After setting registry HKey as suggested in the link, i now do see the desired color schemes in the bare CMD.  however windows power shell still refuse to pick it up.

Comment: Did you check if using `[console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::Utf8` helps as suggested pretty far down in that post? Assuming the OutputEncoding is different from tf8.

Comment: thanks Seth. you are most kind. I did change the OutputEncoding, and it doesn't work.
BodyName          : utf-8
EncodingName      : Unicode (UTF-8)

Comment: What version of Windows/PowerShell are you running? That might make a difference.

Comment: $PSVersionTable.PSVersion:

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      19041  1151