# Why I cannot enter yes when Terraform asks verification for Terraform Apply?

Tags: powershell, terraform

I always stuck to following phase when performing Terraform Apply.

Why I cannot enter yes? I cannot enter any char in PowerShell.

```
Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try this? https://itectec.com/superuser/windows-cannot-type-in-cmd-or-powershell-window-when-run-from-powershell-as-different-user-in-windows-10/

Comment: It looks like the executable your'e calling is emitting VT (Virtual Terminal) escape sequence, support for which isn't enabled by default, though I wouldn't expect that to interfere with prompting for user input. If you want to enable VT sequences to see if it makes a difference, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51681675/45375). Otherwise, please update your question to show the specifics of the invocation of the external executable.

Comment: Tried "Terraform apply | Out-Host", but did not work. Still cannot write yes