# Using backticks to escape characters in sed with PowerShell running on Windows

Tags: powershell, sed

I'm aware that, in PowerShell, backticks(`) are used to escape characters instead of the backslash(\). Hence, when using `sed`, this:

```sh
echo '"where am I"' | sed "s/\"[^\"]*\"/\033[96m&\033[0m/g;"
```

will not work and I would have to write it like this:

```
echo '"where am I"' | sed "s/`"[^\`"]*`"/`e[96m&`e[0m/g;"
```

Hence, I would like to do the same with this code:

```sh
echo '[where am I]' | sed "s/\[\([^09]\)/\033[94m[\033[0m\1/g;"
```

The expected output should be:

[image]

However, when I tried to replace all the backslashes(\) with backticks(`), I can't seem to get the expected output as you can see below:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MikeAnthony I'm using the code to build a program that colors my `ghci` output, you can find the full code [here](https://pastebin.com/YUE2cFnR).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, **GNU `sed` doesn't support *octal* escape sequences - such as `\033` to represent an ESC char. - only *hexadecimal* ones - such as `\x1b`**.

The following command, which uses hex. escape sequences, should therefore work in both POSIX-compatible shells and in PowerShell:

```sh
# Note: Requires *GNU* sed
(echo '[where am I]' | sed 's/\[\([^09]\)/\x1b[94m[\x1b[0m\1/g')
```

In other words:

- **Because the entire, verbatim string ([`'...'`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings)) is interpreted by `sed` itself, there is no need for PowerShell's string interpolation (via [`"..."`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings))**.

Note:

- The enclosing `(...)`, which *on Windows* is required for Windows PowerShell to properly *render* the ANSI escape codes / VT (Virtual Terminal) sequences in the terminal (console) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51681675/45375). It isn't needed if you capture the output in a variable or redirect it.
- In PowerShell, use of `echo` - a built in alias of the [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) cmdlet - isn't necessary and can be omitted, due to PowerShell's *implicit* output behavior.

---

**If your `sed` implementation doesn't support escape sequences such as `\x1b`** - such as on macOS - you must indeed resort to using *PowerShell's* [escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) inside an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings); that is, you must replace `\x1b` with escape sequence `` `e `` in order to embed a *verbatim* ESC character into the string, *up front* (in *Windows PowerShell*, which doesn't support `` `e ``, use subexpression `$([char] 0x1b)` instead):

```sh
# Note: `e only works in PowerShell (Core) 7+
#       In Windows PowerShell, use $([char] 0x1b)
(echo '[where am I]' | sed "s/\[\([^09]\)/`e[94m[`e[0m\1/g")
```

---

**Important**: The above commands contain no embedded `"` characters, which avoids **a long-standing PowerShell bug** that is still present as of PowerShell (Core) 7.2.2:

- The **need to *unconditionally, manually* `\`-escape *embedded* `"` chars.** in arguments passed to *external programs* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375) for details.
- A few quick examples that print verbatim `3" of snow`:

  ```sh
  # Up to at least PowerShell 7.2.2:
  # Without escaping the embedded " with \ (too), 
  # they would in effect be removed from the arguments.
  # Note that pipeline input is *not* affected.

  '3" of snow' | findstr '\"'  # Windows
  /bin/echo '3\" of snow'      # Unix

  # In expandable (double-quoted) strings, you therefore must escape *twice*:
  # once for PowerShell, then for the external-program call.
  '3" of snow' | findstr "\`""  # Windows
  /bin/echo "3\`" of snow"      # Unix
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass non-interpolated expression strings to sed by using single quotes, `'`; e.g., `'a non-interpolated string'`. instead of double quotes around the text. sed would take what it normally does for input. When you use double quotes, that's when powershell escaping comes into play.

Anyway, an alternative to sed would be leveraging the regular expression substitution built into powershell. For instance,

```
Write-Output ('[where am i]' -replace '\[(.*?)\]', "<<`e[5;36m`$1`e[0m>>")
```

Will capture the text between square brackets and place it between "chevrons" and make it blink.

Here's [an article](https://duffney.io/usingansiescapesequencespowershell/) on inserting ANSI in text using powershell.