# Uvicorn colored output does not work on Windows

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn, colorama

I'm using `fastapi` in Python and want to run things like normal with [Uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/). I did a full install of `fastapi` with `pip install "fastapi[all]"` but the Uvicorn colored terminal doesn't work in Command Prompt or Powershell:

[image]

Should look like:

[image]

I understand this is because Windows doesn't use the ANSI color sequences but the Uvicorn docs say it uses `colorama` to provide this support (which I've run separately and works).

As a workaround, I can run Uvicorn with the `--no-use-colors` flag to remove the color flags and make the output readable, but I'd really like coloring if possible.

`uvicorn main:app --reload --no-use-colors`

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/413073/windows-console-with-ansi-colors-handling

Answer (score 2):

If you run [uvicorn programmatically](https://www.uvicorn.org/#running-programmatically), importing `colorama` and initializing with:

```
import colorama
colorama.init()
```

before importing FastAPI seems to get colors working in cmd or powershell on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

As `cdoolin` mentioned, you can use `colorama`. Alternatively, you can [enable ANSI support permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51681675/19846219) or pipe the output to `Out-Host`:

```bash
uvicorn main:app --reload --no-use-colors | Out-Host
```